# Android client not connecting to REST server

Tags: java, android, client-server

I have a Spring Restful Server functional. It accepts requests from any browser and from a Java client that I made to test it.

The problem is when I try to connect to it with Android, whether it is on the emulator or on a smartphone.

I have this simple code in my Java client to test the server:

```
public void requestServer() throws IOException {
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/checkPoints?username=john";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());
}
```

It works perfectly. If I debug it I see that con has the HTTP response code 200, and the response from the page is exactly the number of points that john has.

But if I try it on Android with the same code to be activated when a button is clicked:

```
public void requestServer(View view) throws IOException {
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/checkPoints?username=joao";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());
}
```

It always breaks out in this line:

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
```

If I debug it, I see that the HTTP response code is -1, instead of 200.
I've tried my internal network IP (192.168.1.79 in my case), and it does not work. I've searched in a lot of threads here in Stackoverflow and tried a lot of code that users had, and in all those pieces of code, it always breaks out in the same code, which is that obj.openConnection().

I have the permission for Internet in the manifest, it won't be because of that.

What could it be?

Edit: Here is the stackTrace

```
5-02 19:19:38.109 2769-2769/pt.androidrestfulclient E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        Process: pt.androidrestfulclient, PID: 2769
                                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:289)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                                         Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                                            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
                                                                                            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
                                                                                            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
                                                                                            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
                                                                                            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
                                                                                            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
                                                                                            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
                                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:174)
                                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
                                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
                                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
                                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
                                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
                                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:500)
                                                                                            at pt.ulisboa.tecnico.cmov.androidrestfulclient.MainActivity.requestServer(MainActivity.java:50)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284) 
                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Do you mean that you get an Exception while doing obj.openConnection()? What Exception exactly?

Comment: What is the Exception?, Remember you should running your requestServer method in a second thread like and AsynckTask.

Comment: It is an IllegalStateException, I can print the stackTrace if you want

Comment: print the stacktrace!

Comment: I've tried in the AsyncTask and it returns the same exception

Comment: Added the stackTrace to the original post

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException leads to what @Crash said

Comment: Ok, I'll write the code the the AsycTask now to print the stackTrace in that example

Comment: I tried now AsyncTask from the API (Spring) and it worked by some miracle! I had already tried it before (it was the first I tried) and it never worked. Maybe I had some syntax different and it was firing another exception.

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping `requestServer()` with an Asynctask. Execute this method in doInBackground()

Comment: I had already tried it before and it didn't work. When I wrote the code now to test it and print the StackTrace to you guys it worked by some miracle!

I used code directly from the API(Spring) (it was the first I tried) and it hadn't worked before, but now it is functional!

Thanks for the help